# Notification of Maintenance of the Host which matches “Pausing the VM with in-place migration”

Tags: azure

We have a single VM which is not in available group due the line of Line of Business which run can not be made highly available do the fact of way the application is written.

I have been look at https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/maintenance-notifications

And have a question about maintenance of the underlying host. I understand you will get notify if they need to reboot the host and you can arrange to reboot you VM in your next maintenance window. So that the VM is Power on to another host. But what happens regarding this "If the maintenance does not require a reboot, Azure uses in-place migration to pause the VM while the host is updated" Do you still get notified of when this is going to happen so you can do the same as above and restart the VM to move on to another host or does it just happens when they say it will happen (hopefully this will be out of hours for that region) and your VM will Paused while the maintenance happens on that host.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you do not get a notification if an update is going to be applied which will result in a pause operation. When this happens your machine is only paused for a matter of seconds, so it should have minimal impact.

Comment: Thanks for this, least i have had some clarification from the real world, MS got back to me with the following:

Comment: For the maintenance that does not require a reboot we do not send out a notification. This is because we are able to preform this update without interrupting your VM. 

Although we technically pause your VM it all happens so fast that it does not impact any workloads.

So this update happens seamlessly to the end user. This kind of update also does not require that your VM be moved to a new host. Which is why there is not a reboot happening. A reboot will only happen when we need to move the VM to a new host node.